# What is the difference between x:Name="someName" in SL and ID="someID" in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight, xaml

I have an Asp.Net background and trying to learn Silverlight.

Can you explain, what is the difference between x:Name="someName" in Silverlight, XAML and ID="someID" in Asp.Net markup?

(If they both make a element unique, why one is called Name and the other is called ID ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather *compatibility with ASP.Net* was not one of the requirements considered when they designed Silverlight (which derived in turn from WPF) :)

"ID" is a very technical term whereas "Name" is a bit more human readable. They are after all just the matching *name* of a member of the code-behind class generated at compile time. ID as a term makes more sense for data keys etc.

Classic ASP, and then ASP.Net, date back to before WPF *and way before Silverlight* so the naming is going to be a bit more old-school. Being more recent the naming of most elements tends to be a bit more sensible in Silverlight (compared to ASP).

Note: *This is all just my opinion based on working with all the above technologies for many years.* Hope it helps.

Comment: So they both stand for the same thing but by with a different term?

Comment: @pencilCake: Yes, they both relate to code-behind member naming.